# Copying multiple cells at once

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone quickly tell me what's wrong with this syntax?

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i, "B" & i, "I" & i, "E" & i, "N" & i, "P" & i).Copy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is correct:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i & ",B" & i & ",I" & i & ",E" & i & ",N" & i & ",P" & i).Copy
```

comma `,` should be inserted *as string*. I.e. you're trying to use (which is wrong):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1","B1","I1","E1","N1","P1").Copy
```

but you should use:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1,B1,I1,E1,N1,P1").Copy
```